# MySQL EXISTS or JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `cities` with colums `id`, `name`, `region_id` and table `orders` with colums `id`,`city_id`.

I need select all rows from `orders` where is needed `region_id`.

With `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT `o`.`id`
FROM `orders` as `o`        
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT `id` 
              FROM `cities` 
              WHERE `id` = `o`.`city_id` AND `region_id` = ".$region_id.")
```

With `JOIN`:

```
SELECT `o`.`id`
FROM `orders` as `o` 
LEFT JOIN `cities` as `c` ON `o`.`city_id` = `c`.`id`
WHERE `c`.`region_id` = ".$region_id."
```

What is better in this case?

Comment: What did your own tests reveal?

Comment: I will be test it. But I thought that there is some common opinion on this matter

Answer (score 0):

I would say `JOIN` is the better one due to readability. Fair enough it is easy to understand the `Exit` one, but with a quick look it is less repetition and easier to read.

If you come from a performance perspective, I would advice you to benchmark it on your own system.

I would also recommend you to take advantage of PDO if you are dealing with user inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You should learn to use parameters, so you don't munge query strings.  Stuffing parameter values into a query string can lead to unexpected syntax errors and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

The `LEFT JOIN` is superfluous.  Your `WHERE` clause turns the outer join into an inner join:

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o JOIN
     cities c
     ON o.city_id = c.id
WHERE c.region_id = ".$region_id."
```

(I removed the backticks.  They are unnecessary so they only serve to clutter the query.)

As to which is better, the two can do different things.  The `JOIN` version can return multiple rows for a given order, if `cities` has multiple rows for the same `id`.  Admittedly, this is unlikely with a column called `id`, but the semantics are slightly in favor of `EXISTS`.  Note:  This is only because you are not selecting any other columns from `c`.  If so, the `JOIN` is a no-brainer.

For the most part, the choice is a matter of taste.  You might want to run both versions, check the execution plans, and see which is faster on your data.